# getting error while ionic app run in mobile device using this command( ionic cordova run android)

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework

getting an error while ionic app run on android device on mac

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Felix/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download jdk 1.8 and install again

> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html